# Numpy.delete removes 3 items, but only 2 match condition

Tags: python, numpy

I don't understand the following problem. I want to remove all elements from X and y (both numpy arrays) where y == 3. So if the third and fifth element of y == 3, I want to remove the third and fifth element from X and y.

```
print X.shape
print y.shape
print len(np.where(y == 3))
X = np.delete(X, np.where(y == 3), axis=0)
y = np.delete(y, np.where(y == 3), axis=0)
print X.shape
print y.shape
```

The output is the following:

```
(337L, 10000L)
(337L, 1L)
2
(334L, 10000L)
(334L, 1L)
```

How is it possible that it deletes 3 elements but only 2 match the condition? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that y is 2d, so `np.where` returns a 2-item list, the first element being the array of row indices of the elements of `y` that are 3, the second element being the column indices of those elements. For example if you define `y = np.arange(10)[:,None]`, clearly only one element is three but `np.where(y == 3)` returns `(array([3]), array([0]))`, which has length 2.

Is there a reason why you are not using the simpler solution below?

```
X = X[y[:, 0] != 3]
y = y[y[:, 0] != 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was helpful and your solution even better.